# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none) Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, pip

**Solved**
Look in answers for the answer...

whenever I try to install tensor flow I get the rest error above

OS: Mac Big Sur 11.6 (20G165)

Python version: Python 3.10.0

pip version: pip 21.2.4

first I made a venv: python3 -m venv --system-site-packages ./venv

then I activated it: source ./venv/bin/activate  # sh, bash, or zsh

Upgraded pip: pip install --upgrade pip

Finally tried to install tensor flow and it errored out with the error message above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It might be that your Python version is too new for tensorflow. The latest version only lists up to Python 3.9: https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it :/ but thank for the suggestion :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out, just followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykCY_tJbhNw worked like a charm, first I had to uninstall python10, the current version of python is python8.
Hope this helped people with this doubt :)